# How create different page for every different posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a website where I am required to have individual pages for every different posts. I have to put 8 posts in eight different styles and properties, that is why I need those pages.

For example as we know for each page template we can make something like

```
page-templateone.php
```

Like that I want something similar for posts, just for example:

```
post-numberone.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a following `php` file in your theme folder

`single-{post_type}-{post_slug}.php`

For example, you have a post with a slug `very-important-post`. To have a template for this post alone, you need to create a file called `single-post-very-important-post.php`

If you'd like to be able to select template from the post editing screen, in 4.7 post type templates became available. Read more [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/)
If you'd like to be able to do it in the older verion, take a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2769/13986)